# How do I get the maximum value of a hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, max

Given a hash whose values are all numeric, I thought I read in some other SO post this was done by

```
hash.max_by{|k,v| v}
```

but this returns an array, which I don't want.  I want the greatest value in my hash.

Comment: Just do `hash.max_by{|k,v| v}.to_h`. Note: `#to_h` works only for Ruby 2.x of above versions. For Ruby 1.9 or lower do: `Hash[hash.max_by{|k,v| v}]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use the `max` method on the `values` of the hash:

```
{a: 1, b: 2}.values.max
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.max_by(&:last).last
```

makes a single pass through the array.  By contrast @Bustikiller's code makes two passes, but I suspect it's still faster than the above.